# Why things are so different in a driver class ("static void main") and a class definition?

Tags: constructor

I know some of the terms I use are confusing. To clarify, a driver class is basically one built on a class definition (starting with public class...) but is a method itself with the header **public static void main (String args[])**.

The point of this post is to resolve my **serious** confusion. (I am a beginner in programming)

**to me**, since a driver class is a method, all it does is to implement itself. But things kinda turn out to be the opposite . For example:

> to implement a constructor in a driver class, you simply put down the constructor heading, like public Rectangle(), with its name being the same as that of the class. **but** in a class definition, to creat a object/ implement a constructor, you also have to write down happen inside that constructor, so you use the expression "type name = new type name ()".

PS: I might have used some terms  wrongly, correct me thanks. Or some concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer this the best way that I can.

Let's look at each of the keywords in a "driver class method" and determine the meaning.

1. public - this method is publicly callable by a class outside of it
2. static - this method is callable WITHOUT an instance of the class. In Java, look at the Math class. You don't need to instantiate an instance of the Math class to use the sqrt function (Math m = New Math(); m.sqrt(25);), you can just use Math.sqrt(25).
3. void - this method returns nothing
4. main - name of the method

Now that we have that cleared up, let's ask ourselves why these things have to be here for a "driver class"

The Virtual Machine (the program that runs your custom programs) is hard coded to look for a method named main that is public and can also be called WITHOUT CREATING AN INSTANCE OF YOUR CLASS.

So this means that when your program first runs, there is no instance of it.

To counter this, you can either create all of your methods and properties as static (generally considered bad practice) OR you can create an instance of your own class inside of it's own entry method, and begin to call the non-static methods and properties that belong to the instance.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Is virtual machine basically a Java IDE?

Comment: When you said to creat non static method inside a driver class, do you mean to basically treat it as a class definition? (A class definition usually contains all the method implemented for use in drive class)

Comment: No, and IDE is NOT a Virtual Machine. An IDE is just another program that is written to make it easier for a developer to write code. You need to know the difference between a compiled and interpreted language. See this article for an in depth explanation. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696764/Differences-between-compiled-and-Interpreted-Langu

Comment: To your second comment, yes treat it like a class. A class is a class is a class regardless of what is inside. You can either implement your (beginner) solution all in one class, or have another class that contains the bulk of your logic. As you get more into it, and into software design, you'll get a better sense of how to divide your program up into classes, methods, etc.